# Format list spacing enumitem, topsep does not work

Tags: lists, enumitem

I am trying to create a list within a table. However, I have a problem with the spacing before and after the list. I do not want any additional spacing due to the itimze/list etc. The first bullet point should start right after the line above and the cells below should also start right after. 
The topsep option does not seem to work here, even when set to 0 etc. Some is true for the bottom. 
Is this due to any other packages/format options etc. used? Or is there a hint?
Thanks a lot in advance

```
\documentclass[10pt, headinclude]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, fancyhdr, booktabs}  
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\headheight = 15pt
\lhead{ipsum}
\chead{}
\rhead{November 2014}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{p{0.16\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}   
\newcommand\VRule{\color{black}\vrule width 0.2pt}

\begin{document}

%Header line
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\centerline{\begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\linewidth} \begin{center} \LARGE \bf
Mustermann
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}

\vspace{25pt}

\centerline{\begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\linewidth} \begin{center}
lipsum
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
\vspace{10pt}

\section*{Personal Details}
lispum
\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
10/2011-03/2014             & \textbf{Uni of Witchcraft}\\ lorem ipsum \\
                            & \begin{itemize}[noitemsep, nolistsep, topsep=0pt]
                            \item lorem et al:
                            \item `Lorem con temperum'
                            \item  Veni, vedi, vici     
                            \end{itemize} \\ [5pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is to enclose the list inside a `minipage` so that the spaces are gobbled.

```
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
10/2011-03/2014             & \textbf{Uni of Witchcraft}\\
lorem ipsum & just a dummy line\\
                            & \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                            \begin{itemize}[nosep]
                            \item lorem et al:
                            \item `Lorem con temperum'
                            \item  Veni, vedi, vici
                            \end{itemize}
                            \end{minipage} \\ %[5pt]
                            & another dummy line
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Regarding the comment:

If you want some space at the bottom of the list, you can use `before` and `after` keys provided by `enumitem` and insert vertical space by yourself:

```
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
10/2011-03/2014             & \textbf{Uni of Witchcraft}\\
lorem ipsum & just a dummy line\\
                            &
                            \begin{itemize}[before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},nosep]
                            \item lorem et al:
                            \item `Lorem con temperum'
                            \item  Veni, vedi, vici
                            \end{itemize}
                             \\ [5pt]
                            & another dummy line
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, how do I add the [5pt] spacing? It does not work anymore. Now the minipage is followed right after by the next row of the table, but I do want some space, without having to add a complete dummy line.

Comment: @greentex Please see the update.